# Suddenly my kitten is fearing me?

Tags: cats, fear

My little kitty cat was very playful but after a small incident he got very very very much scared of everything, even including his toys. He used to come to me when he feal sleepy but not anymore. Sometimes he comes but just looks at me and do little meow. If I hold him, he try's to run. So now I try not to force him. So how can I make him get back to normal the way he was before?
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some dos/don'ts for soothing a freaked out cat?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6494)

Comment: Also related [How can I get my cat to not be afraid of me?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10441)

Answer (score 2):

That happens sometimes if the toy you are playing with accidentally hits them and it freaks them out.  That happened with one of mine. It took a while for her to not be scared.  But she came around. She is rather feral too and that can make it take longer too.
Just be gentle and patient. They will come around.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the age of the kitten then they shouldn't be fearful for long. The younger they are the soon r r they forget. Sounds like you have a sensitive cat. My 4 month old kitten liked to be startled, he then tries to Chase us back.